# Is this normal? Below EV

Tags: ev

Is it normal if I'm running 11.500 big blinds below EV in all-in pots over 700.000 hands? What are the chances for this to occur? My standard deviation BB/100 is about 100.

Comment: How many all-in hands did you play?

Comment: There are 6700 hands where the showdown has occurred without any action taken on the river.

Comment: I would say off the cuff that there is no normal, it really depends on how many of these all-ins are bluffs in relation to nuts.

Comment: My average equity in those all-in hands is 50.3%, and I have won 50.6% of those hands so that part is fine, but it seems that I have won way more hands (about 51%) when I have invested less than 60BB to the pot, so I guess that's where the EV difference comes from. I'll play another 200K hands, if nothing changes I'll try some other sites to play at. If someone interested I can show the graph.